# Restrictive user image uploads in dnn replies to blogs/forums

Tags: dotnetnuke

In our DNN website, users can reply to forum and blog posts and they'll be using DNN rich text editor to do this. But we'd want to enable users to attach files and upload images as part of their replies. And when they upload images, they do it to a common folder as configured & permitted (for their respective roles) in the host file management using Image Manager.

Is there any configuration in DNN core that puts user uploaded files/images in separate folders so that the uploaded content (images/files) is only visible to them in the Image/Document Manager and not to others.

Any inputs to achieve this appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Forum module you are using, DNN has "personal" folders now that user can upload files into.

If you're using the latest version of DNN, you can use the default folder permissions and allow the users to upload/reference those images, and then remove the permissions from other folders to prevent future uploads there.